# Can I refresh the credentials fetched by AWS STS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sts

I am trying to get a temporary credential via `sts.assumeRole`, and construct a `Credentials` object and S3 object when lambda cold starts. In each request, I use the `credentails.getPromise` to retrieve the credential, but seems not working. Do I have to call `sts.assumeRole` again to get the credential when it is expired?

The code is like below:

```js
  import { STS, Credentials } from 'aws-sdk';
  
  async function getS3AndCredentials () {
    const sts = new STS()
    const data = await sts.assumeRole(params).promise();
    const credentials = new Credentials(
      data.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
      data.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
      data.Credentials.SessionToken,
    );
    return {s3: new S3({credentials}), credentials}
  }

  const {s3, credentials} = await getS3AndCredentials()

  // In lambda handler
  async function handler() {

    /* From AWS document
     * Gets the existing credentials, refreshing them if necessary, and returns
     * a promise that will be fulfilled immediately (if no refresh is necessary)
     * or when the refresh has completed.
    */
    await credentials.getPromise() // I hope here it will get the credentials for each request

    s3.putObject({..}) // but after running a while, s3 complain expired of the token
  }
```

Comment: I’d just fetch the credentials every time your lambda is invoked. Or run it under that role from the start

Comment: @DanielA.White thanks, retrieving credential through sts and the create a s3 client in each request seem very expensive.

Comment: If run that role from the start, it is possible the lambda will live longer after the credential get expired.